# php preg_match returning unexpected true

Tags: php, regex

Could anyone explain to me why this is returning `TRUE`? There are 7 z's yet it should be returning `FALSE` because I've set a max limit of 6 in the regex.

```
preg_match('/z{4,6}/', "zzzzzzz")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because your string includes a substring of 4 to 6 'z's. If you want the match to be against your whole string, you have to put in the anchors in your regex.

```
/^z{4,6}$/
```

or

```
/\Az{4,6}\z/
```

Comment: @Chris: to clarify, ^ and $ are start and end of string respectively (or newline if using modifiers but lets not complicate things). So the regex here says "start of string, followed by 4 to 6 z's followed by end of string"